# How do I upload 4 GSE12050_GSM304448.gpr microarrays files?

Tags: r, import

I need to load the 4 GenePix files (Agilent microarrays) into R, making sure to extract the foreground and background median values from the Cy5 and Cy3 channels, using marray library.

Your help with command lines is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://bioconductor.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/packages/3.5/bioc/vignettes/marray/inst/doc/marray.pdf

Comment: What do I insert instead of 'swirlTargets', as per the example in this document?                                                                                                      
      > data <- read.GenePix(targets=swirlTargets)                        
                                                                                       
        "If your working directory contains GenePix files ( .gpr), run the following command. By
default, the function read.GenePix will also set up printer layout and probe annotation
information.
> data <- read.GenePix(targets=swirlTargets) "